# Google Cloud storage, Object Insert?

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

When I `r.FormFile("name")` from the `*http.Request` I get a file (`f`), file header (`fh`) and an error (`err`). When I try to save the object into a bucket with :

`service.Objects.Insert("bucketName", f).Do()`

I get a mismatch of types, `multipart.File` != `*storage.Object`

I suspect I might have to `io.Copy`...

Comment: Which client library are you using?

Comment: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage but there is another one which is confusing https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1. The error I get is `account is read only` but I have set up IAM permissions etc..